# java android copy files assets

Tags: java, android, file, copy, assets

I have Async Task that must write folder "Files" from assets to folder on SD-card. But nothing work.

```
final String sdDir = "/sdcard/izuchaika/";

new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                InputStream in = getAssets().open("Files");
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(sdDir));
                try {
                    byte[] bucket = new byte[32 * 1024];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while (bytesRead != -1) {
                        bytesRead = in.read(bucket);
                        out.write(bucket, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (in != null)
                            in.close();
                        if (out != null)
                            out.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }).start();
```

[Screen of folder tree](http://s017.radikal.ru/i401/1111/25/7ab9f578a20d.jpg)

Comment: General tip: *Never* hardcode a path to the external storage/sdcard *(as you did in line 1 of your code)*. Use [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) instead, since the actual path and the type of storage varies between devices *(some have inbuilt flash instead of an SD-card for example)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing and reading directories as files.

Replace

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("Files");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(sdDir));
```

with

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("Files/exit.png");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(sdDir+"/exit.png"));
```

Comment: and, remember to ask for permission to write to SD Card in the manifest

Comment: InputStream in = getAssets().open("Files/exit.png");

But this way I'll can read only files?
I need to read all folder because there are a lot of files.

Comment: Then list the files in the assets directory and make a loop. What is the problem?